# Rottweiler - need a durable chewing toy or ball - desperate owner

Tags: dogs, play, toys, chewing, agility

I own a female Rottweiler, about 2 years old.

I've tried every kind of chewing toy. The only ones she can't destroy are the silicon made ones, but the silicon ball is too heavy for her and she gets bored.

Do you have any advice on which play toy that she could chew and which would be resistant to chewing-related damage?

I was looking for something I can throw if possible, so that she can use it at home and outside.

She loves balls more than bones, she get bored with fake bones in few days / hours.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to dogs (I only had cats) but wouldn't 2 year old dogs be growing out of playing with toys?

Comment: She's much of the time alone at home i would love to find something to entertain her during the day

Comment: @D.Tanya in my experience dogs only grow out of playing with toys in the last few weeks or months of their life. My fifteen year old cattle-kelpie-x still Ioves play time every night and he is seriously crippled following a dog attack. In fact I personally believe his play time keeps him young at heart.

Comment: There are only a couple of brands I've found that actually survive. I'll post as answer once I'm home and can identify which ones they are. In my experience Kong toys are not always reliable - only the original Kong.

Answer (score 4):

Variety is the spice of life, even for dogs. 
Keep her busy and entertained by alternating the types of chew toys she gets every day. Here's a few more options:

- [A Kong Toy](https://www.kongcompany.com/) - These are super durable rubber toys that are hollow on the inside. You can fill them with a bit of peanut butter or other food, which will keep your dog busy all day. The website has a few more ideas for recipes/fillers. There are plenty of other interactive food/puzzle toys, but a large chew-oriented dog like yours might be more prone to actually destroying the toy rather than solving the puzzle.
- Pupcicles - Basically just an ice block with food frozen into it. These are super easy to make and used as enrichment in zoos all over the country. They're especially great on hot days (outside, of course). You can freeze treats or toys into it, or flavor the whole block with a bit of chicken or beef broth. I like to freeze carrots and apple slices in for my dog. Just make sure whatever you freeze in is not [a food dangerous to dogs](http://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control/people-foods-avoid-feeding-your-pets)
- Another dog. This option is a bit extreme, but remember that dogs are highly social pack animals. They like having company all the time, and don't do well being left alone for long stretches of time. Another dog is a big commitment, but a second dog will help keep her entertained and give her someone to play with. If you do decide to go this route, just make sure she gets along well with the other dog before you decide to adopt.

Comment: i would love to have another dog, just you know a big dog is very impegnative, i know about Kong maybe it worths trying it, thank you for your suggestions!  I will leave this question open for the moment to see if any other idea is out there :) i'll upvote your, thanks

Comment: Actually i already ordered one toy hoping it is durable, it's the Jolly Ball http://www.equinegiftcompany.co.uk/ekmps/shops/theequinegift/images/jolly-ball-horse-toy-179-p.jpg Some says it's very durable, I HOPE :D However many says Kong could be the only one to save me, just i don't like the fact she has to fight to get food :P

Answer (score 3):

Really important advice... THE GOLDEN RULE...

You can teach a dog to treat his or her toys with greater respect. How you ask?

If your dog begins to treat the toy with damaging results, remove the toy immediately and place in a visible but inaccessible (to the dog) location for at least 24 hours. After that time has passed and preferably at a similar time of day (dogs love routine) return the toy to circulation, but this time keep a closer watch and, if your four legged friend begins to repeat the destructive behaviour, again remove the toy and place in the same visible but inaccessible location.

Repeat this process for at least seven days. If the behaviour does not improve during this time, I'm not certain what else to suggest, except maybe longer periods between the return of the toy to circulation.

Here is a photo of my fella's favourite **and** most robust toys...

[image: Bill the Brown Dog's Favourite Toys]

If and when the link fails... In order of "robustness" and favour...

1. The green squeaky toys Ee-Ee (left in photo) and Aw-Aw (right in photo) are the oldest and by far the most robust. Ee-Ee the "squid" (it's a guess, we've never truly figured it out) is over ten years old and surprisingly maintained its squeak, after which it was named, until last year. I'm not certain about Ee-Ee but know for certain that Aw-Aw is manufactured by JW Pet Company Inc, based in Teterboro, NJ, USA. Aw-Aw is dated 2007. They are of very similar thick rubber-like material and have been treated brutally and extensively both inside and outside, Ee-Ee more so than Aw-Aw.
2. Red-Rope has been a long time favourite and despite suffering some significant unravelling has been and still is a favourite chewing toy and popular wrestling toy.
3. Yellow-Duckie taught us the golden rule detailed above. Yellow-Duckie was one of three, however one sibling was left behind at a holiday destination and the other lost a wing. Yellow-Duckie still squeaks although occasionally the squeaker needs to be reinserted. Yellow-Duckie was purchased in 2005 and is the currently preferred throw and catch toy.
4. Ruffous (the dog) is a recent purchase (two years ago) that was expected to last a week or two. Application of the golden rule detailed above has significantly prolonged Ruffous' life. Despite loss of coat, tail and minor limbs, Ruffous still squeaks and is popular but treated with a little more care by Bill the Brown Dog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i like the green ones, problem with my dog is she eat cloths :( thanks a lot and your dog is fantastic :D very funny thanks i'll upvote